# Create new column in Pandas and fill down with a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to create a new column to my dataset and fill down this column with a specific value

**Data**

```
id       start  stat
d_in     din    8
d_in     din    8
hello       
hi       din    8
```

**Desired**

```
plan    id      start   stat
21      d_in    din     8
21      d_in    din     8
21      hello       
21      hi      din     8
```

**Doing**

```
df['plan'] = df['plan'].fillna('21')
```

However, this is not actually creating the new column. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: just df['new_column'] = 21 should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply try: `df['plan'] = '21'`

Or `df['plan'] = 21` if an integer type is wanted.

Pandas will automatically broadcast scalars to all rows.